# Template declaration of decltype with g++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, clang++, g++4.9

The following code works fine with clang version 3.6.0.
But when I use it with g++ 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 
I get an error :

```
//g++ -std=c++14 testgcc.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto doSomething(){
  return 123;
}

template<typename T>
decltype(doSomething<T>()) result = doSomething<T>();

decltype(doSomething<int>()) result2 = result<int>;

int main(void){
  cout<<result2<<endl;
}
```

The error I get is :

```
testgcc.cpp:12:28: error: template declaration of ‘decltype (doSomething<T>()) result’
 decltype(doSomething<T>()) result = doSomething<T>();
                            ^
testgcc.cpp:14:40: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
 decltype(doSomething<int>()) result2 = result<int>;
                                        ^
testgcc.cpp:14:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 decltype(doSomething<int>()) result2 = result<int>;
```

Is there a way I can get the code to compile with gcc? Thanks. p.s. I clearly don't need the `template <typename T>` but this is just for illustration.

Comment: Compile fine with gcc 5.2 [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2484afd652ace119)

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah thank you I will try to download the latest gcc and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [C++1y/C++14 Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html), variable templates are not supported by g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: OK thank you. It seems to work in gcc 5.2 according to Jarod42. Will accept this answer in a couple of minutes.